# Set default value for a DateTime field in Schema.xml in Sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint

I want to set the default value for DateTime field that I created in Sharepoint 2010 in the XML file.

I couldn't find any information about how to set a fixed date as default. Almost every example is using

```
<Default>[today]</Default>
```

If I want to set the date to "01/01/2001" how should I put the value.

```
<Default>1/1/2001</Default>
<Default>"1/1/2001"</Default>
<Default>=Date("1/1/2001")</Default>
```

Please help me to know which one is the correct way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go :

```
<Default>2001-01-01T00:00:00Z</Default>
```